# Dynamic state is not getting updated in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react js , here

```
this.state = {
      technologies: [],
      showLowError: false,
      showHighError: false,
      showMediumError: false
    }
```

I have this state variables.

Now,

What I am trying to do is ,

```
if(type === "Low") {
        errorState = "showLowError";
      } else if(type === "Medium") {
        errorState = "showMediumError";
      } else {
        errorState = "showHighError";
      }
      if (tobeupdated === "count") {
        let validateData = this.validate(type, noc);
        console.log("validateData is ==>", validateData);
        this.setState({
          [errorState]: validateData
        })
      }
```

update the state, depend upon some variables, Now,

[errorState] is not updating the exact value, Value for the state is not getting set.can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Make sure you have the react class's `this` context bound to your function. can you give us a codepen with this not working? its hard to know why a setstate isn't working without testing.

Comment: and a slight optimization... just do one assignment for errorState. `errorState = \`show${type}Error\`;`

Comment: errorState = `show${type}Error;`   I did thin now , do I need to have  [errorState] ?

Comment: Or just errorState : validateData will be fine ?

Comment: Using this now still it does not update the state

Comment: You still need the brackets round the key. In javascript that is the syntax to denote a variable and or dynamic key

Comment: of course it wont fix ur problem. like i said its a little optimization so you dont write out all that code to find out what your key is.

Comment: Hi, Its updating the state now, But I do have one issue

Comment: Great so we can consider this question complete :) feel free to post a new question with your new issue if you cant figure it out! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
 this.setState(this.state);
```

after:

```
 this.setState({
      [errorState]: validateData
    })
```